Uniqueness validation with 2 scopes not acting as expected
I have a model with a uniqueness validation that keeps failing despite my scopes.
# A member of a Group
class GroupItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :groupable, polymorphic: true, optional: true

  # You can only be a member of a group once
  validates_uniqueness_of_without_deleted :groupable_id, uniqueness: { scope: %i[group_id groupable_type] }
end

When I create 2 separate groups and attempt to join each with the same record it fails validation when I believe it should be valid since the group_id is different.
client = Client.create
group1 = Group.create
group2 = Group.create

group_item_1 = GroupItem.create(group: group1, groupable: client)
group_item_2 = GroupItem.new(group: group2, groupable: client)

> group_item_1
#<GroupItem:0x000000012ac86a60> {
                :id => 6,
    :groupable_type => "Client",
      :groupable_id => 7,
          :group_id => 7,
        :deleted_at => nil,
        :created_at => Fri, 07 Jun 2024 16:03:29.705078000 EDT -04:00,
        :updated_at => Fri, 07 Jun 2024 16:03:29.705078000 EDT -04:00
}

> group_item_2
#<GroupItem:0x000000011f77db00> {
                :id => nil,
    :groupable_type => "Client",
      :groupable_id => 7,
          :group_id => 8,
        :deleted_at => nil,
        :created_at => nil,
        :updated_at => nil
}

> group_item_2.valid?
false

> group_item_2.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000012aae5fd0 @base=#<GroupItem id: nil, groupable_type: "Client", groupable_id: 7, group_id: 8, deleted_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @errors=[#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=groupable_id, type=taken, options={:uniqueness=>{:scope=>[:group_id, :groupable_type]}, :value=>7}>]>

What am I doing wrong with this validation?

What GroupItem.where(groupable_type: "Client", groupable_id: 7, group_id: 8) shows? And what is real situation in the database? (act_as_paranoid is anti pattern gem)

What is it that you actually intended to do with this validation? If you want to ensure that an item can only be added to a group once you need to have  groupable_id in that scope. %i[group_id groupable_type groupable_id]. As written it will only let you add one kind of item of a type to a group.

@max that is what I'm trying to do but the validation still doesn't pass

@mechnicov it comes back with an empty array which is why I don't understand what's going wrong.
